# PyQt5 QLabel hyperlink tooltip/hovertext

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Why this is not working or any simple alternative to this:

```
label= QLabel("<b>Name</b>: ABC | <b>Contact</b>: <a style='text-decoration:none;color:black'href='mailto:abc@gmail.com' title='this is a link to email'>abc@gmail.com</a>")
label.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```

Everything works fine except the title.
How can i show a hover text when this link is hovered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt supports only a [limited subset of HTML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html), which doesn't include the 'title' keyword of anchors.

On the other hand, QLabel has the [`linkHovered`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#linkHovered) signal, which can be used to show a QToolTip:

```
titles = {
    'mailto:abc@gmail.com': 'this is a link to email'
}

def hover(url):
    if url:
        QToolTip.showText(QCursor.pos(), titles.get(url, url))
    else:
        QToolTip.hideText()

label= QLabel("<b>Name</b>: ABC | <b>Contact</b>: <a style='text-decoration:none;color:black'href='mailto:abc@gmail.com'>abc@gmail.com</a>")
label.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
label.linkHovered.connect(hover)
```